# Add a link to the revision list for editors

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, revisions-list

I think a another link for "revisions" next to "edit | flag" would be useful for those over 2000 rep who need a quick look at the revision history.

(I'm too lazy to keep typing in "revisions/id/list")

Comment: o_o How would you even know about revisions/##/list if there wasn't an easy way to access it?

Comment: Because I've found plenty of links. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't you just click the TimeStamp on the edit? It'll take you to the revision list.

Comment: That's what I do.

Comment: I would have thought thats what everyone does :P

Comment: Doh! I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if questions which haven't been edited had a link to that somewhere. ( *They currently don't* )

I don't think it is really required on most questions/answers, but it might be a good idea from a usability standpoint.

Comment: Don't really see a point to that, as all you would get would be revision 1.

Comment: well, it can be useful if there are state changes to the question that aren't technically edits, but are documented in revision history. Like lock/unlock, etc.

Comment: Are state changes in the current revision history? I can't remember seeing any but it's a good chance that is just my faulty memory.